# Alias for TypeScript arrays

Tags: c#, javascript, typescript

I want to do a translation of `C#` code below into `TypeScript`:

```
[JsType(JsMode.Json)]
public class position : JsArray<JsNumber>
{
}

[JsType(JsMode.Json)]
public class coordinateArray : JsArray<position>
{
}

[JsType(JsMode.Json)]
public class polygonRings : JsArray<coordinateArray>
{
}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
export interface position {
    (): number[];
}

export interface coordinateArray {
    (): position[];
}

export interface polygonRings {
    (): coordinateArray[];
}
```

But when I try to cast it I have some problems:

> Cannot convert 'coordinateArray' to 'position[]'.

In code:

```
(<position[]> lineString.coordinates).push(position);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the constructor method on an instance of `coordinateArray` would return type `position[]`, but using the interface as a type wouldn't give you something compatible with `position[]`.

If you have code that otherwise works, except for the compiler warning, you can tell the compiler you know better using:

```
(<position[]><any> ca)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export interface coordinateArray {
    (): position[];
}
```

What you've described isn't an array, it's a function type that, when invoked, returns an array:

```
var x: coordinateArray = ...;
var y = x(); // y: position[]
```

You probably want to define an index signature instead:

```
export interface coordinateArray {
    [index: number]: position;
}
```

This won't convert directly to a `position[]` because it's still not actually an array (a real `position[]` would have methods like `splice` and `push`, but `coordinateArray` doesn't), but is at least correct about what the shape of the type is.